# How do I reproduce results from webgraphviz with python graphviz using 2 column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have a two column pandas dataframe with parent and child process id's that looks like the following:

```
    ChildID ParentID
0   460     580
1   580     716
2   460     724
3   716     840
4   716     812
5   724     884
6   716     800
7   1424    2028
8   2280    2368
9   2368    2480
10  2948    2916
11  3312    3896
12  3312    3468
13  3312    3996
16  4       460
17  460     480
18  3244    4168
19  1324    4796
20  5888    5048
21  2504    4424
22  1324    7584
23  2040    1400
24  1224    2452
..  ...     ...
```

I have downloaded the graphviz python library, but in the meantime to see what I could do I headed over to http://www.webgraphviz.com/ to see what could be done.  I used the same dataset and it looks pretty good.

[image: ParentChild-WebGraphViz]

I have searched a bit but am having trouble finding a good way to replicate this using the python library graphviz.  Can anyone point me in the right direction just using 2 columns with possibly a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
from graphviz import Graph
g = Graph('processs', filename='process.gv', engin='sfdp')
# run over all the rows and for each row add a new edge to the graph
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g.edge(str(row['ChildID']), str(row['ParentID']))
g.view()
```

If you have some problems with running graphviz on windows you probably need to add graphviz's bin files to the windows PATH, to do so you can use:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + <path to the bin folder>
```

Enjoy!